# Button Command not execute function

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have created a button and I link it to an ICommand NavigateToVM but it does not hit the execute function when I try to click the button. I am I doing something wrong. I'll post the code that is relevant. Thanks in advance.
The Profile button is the button I am trying to get to work. It is just a standard Icommand.

```
{
    public class NavigationBarVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand NavigateToVMCmd { get; set; }
        public NavigationBarVM()
        {

        }
        public NavigationBarVM( NavigationStore _navigationStore)
        {
            NavigateToVMCmd = new NavigateToProfileCommand(this, _navigationStore);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace WpfNotes.Commands
{
    public class NavigateToProfileCommand : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly NavigationBarVM navBarVM;
        private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;

        public NavigateToProfileCommand(NavigationBarVM VM, NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            navBarVM = VM;
            _navigationStore = navigationStore;
        }
        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = new ProfileVM();
            Debug.WriteLine("Stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfNotes.View.NavigationBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfNotes.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:VM ="clr-namespace:WpfNotes.ViewModel">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <VM:NavigationBarVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        
    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Height="40">
         <Button BorderThickness="0" Content="Profile" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path = NavigateToVMCmd }"></Button>
    </UniformGrid>
        
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question.

Comment: How is `NavigationBarVM` created? You have two ctors, are you sure it's initialized with the one assigning a value to `NavigateToVMCmd`?

Comment: `<VM:NavigationBarVM x:Key="vm"/>` does of course call the parameterless constructor. So NavigateToVMCmd is apparently never initialized. A UserControl will typically not have its own, private view model. Maybe removing the NavigationBarVM resource and binding to the parent view model with `Command="{Binding NavigateToVMCmd}"` is all you need to do.

Comment: Is it necessary to set the datacontext to the view model in the code behind? I removed the Usercontrol resource but now it cannot find the navigatetiVMCmd binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the `NavigationBarVM` programmatically and inject it with a `NavigationStore`:

```
public partial class NavigationBar : UserControl
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new NavigationBarVM(new NavigationStore());
    }
}
```

You can then bind directly to the command of the view model:

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Content="Profile"
        Command="{Binding NavigateToVMCmd}" />
```

The following initializes the `NavigationBarVM` using the default constructor which is pretty useless and should be removed in your case as it doesn't initialize the command:

```
<VM:NavigationBarVM x:Key="vm"/>
```